# setup timer for a node

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit, sknode

im trying to set a timer for every node that create (by touching the screen). I want to set up a timer to know when to remove the node (by using removefromparent). I want that if some node is in locate in some position for 5 second then it remove from the screen.
im new for swift and I don't really get how should I set the timer. I use this init:

```
let ballTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false, block: <#T##(Timer) -> Void#>)
```

I understood that the "withTimeInterval" is for setting the second - so I set it to 1.  the "repeats" and the "block" properties I don't really get and so im not sure if im using the right function.

can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `update()` function of your scene.  That override runs every frame so you can check your positioning then, and keeping track of each node, you can start or restart a `wait()` action that removes the node on completion.

Something like,

```
if ball.position.x == 200 && ball.position.y == 200 {
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, remove])

    ball.run(sequence)
}else{
    ball.removeAllActions()
}
```

Note: you should not use specific coordinates like that though, use a range of at least a few points or round up the x and y values.

Comment: tnx! how do I using range?

Comment: ‘ if ball.position.x >= 199 && ball.position.x <= 201 {'

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spritekit it is not necessary to use timers. Spritekit has it's own built in timing mechanism with the game loop calling Update, as well as ways of running actions with a designated time to trigger an event.

```
let ball = SKSpriteNode(color: red, size: CGSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
ball.zPosition = 1
ball.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
addChild(ball)

let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 5.0)
let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, remove])

ball.run(sequence)
```

Comment: that not what I actually looking for, I want to remove the node(ball) if its position is in some point and its there  for 5 seconds.

Comment: you didn't say that in your post, I suggest you modify it to reflect your question better

Comment: just fix it, thanks! maybe you can help me with that?

Comment: This is the way to go,  try keeping your update loop free from clutter

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helpers! what I eventually did is this:

```
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    self.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "BALL") { (node:SKNode, nil) in
        if node.position.y <= 25 || node.position.x <= 50 {
            let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0)
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, remove])
            print("in range")
            node.run(sequence)
        }
    }
}
```

first, I run it through update function, then I search for the node by its name (BALL), and then I use heValyreanGroup  answer to remove it from the view.

Comment: This is a terrible way to handle your code.  What you are doing is searching your scene root for anything called ball, and processing during every frame.  This is a big time waster.  i would recommend preserving what you find, so that you do not need to search every time.  To make this a little bit more clear for you.  Let's say you have an encyclopedia book B and you are writing a book report on ball.  Now imagine having to search for "Ball" every time you need it,  it would be time consuming.  Instead you place a bookmark at Ball, so that you quickly access it the next time you need it.

Comment: Ok, I post my answer so I can get a feedback and opinions on it. First, thank you! Second, do you have a better way and can you show me how to use it?